# Glassfish start-cluster command fails

Tags: glassfish, cluster-computing, restart, asadmin

I'm attempting to restart a glassfish server (glassfish3?) using a script which runs daily, which executes the following commands:

```
asadmin stop-cluster myapp-cluster
asadmin start-cluster myapp-cluster
```

However, either command just gives the ouptut:

```
autoscaling.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

The server lives on Amazon, obviously. Any idea why it's failing, or better yet, how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, I logged into the asadmin, and at the prompt, typed "start-domain". That started the domain. After that, I typed "start-cluster myapp-cluster", and now the app is up.

So, apparently for some reason the domain was down. Probably it would be a good idea to modify the script to stop the cluster, stop the domain, then start the domain, and start the cluster. Ideally, glassfish would stop going down every few days...